# Analyzing nested categorical data

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, experiment-design, nested-data

I need to compare binary responses (nectar present/absent) between flowers of two treatments ("y" and "n"). This seems like a straight forward case for a Chi-square test, however- my design involved a couple of layers of nesting (site/plant).

What is the best way to account for nesting in a categorical analysis?

Example data below

```
site    plant   flower   status   nectar_present
ek      11      102      n        0
ek      11      103      y        0
ek      11      104      n        1
ek      11      105      y        0
ek      11      106      n        1
ek      11      107      y        0
ek      11      108      n        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a binary (yes/no) response variable, so logistic regression would be a natural starting point. But the nesting structure means that the usual independence assumption would fail. That can be modeled with a random effects model (or *mixed model*), in R with the `lme4` package. If you will post (a link to) the data I can have a look. Assuming enough observations, something like the following code:

```
library(lme4)
mod0 <- glmer( status ~ (1 | site/plant), data=your_data_frame, family=binomial )
```

will fit a pure random effects model. Fixed effects can also be included. Many examples on this site, for instance [Specifying and Interpreting Mixed effects logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391180/specifying-and-interpreting-mixed-effects-logistic-regression/391233#391233) and many others.